# For loop, runs once?

Tags: php, for-loop, opencart

I'm using OpenCart and I'm trying to achieve rendering out the meta_description (used to identify the comic publisher) and use it to make a drop-down list with sub-categories, or to give the illusion of it. Here is my code now, it's an adopted version of the current OpenCart code. ['class'] is how I grab the child categories meta_description.

Basically, the second for statement doesn't work - it only does the first one. I would appreciated any kind of support on this.

```
    <div class="menu">
     <div id="top"></div>
    <span>          
        <ul id="nav">
            <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
            <li><a href="#"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
                <?php if ($category['children']) { ?> 
                <div class="subs">
                    <div>
                        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($category['children']);) { ?>
                        <ul>
                            <?php $j = $i + ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column']); ?>                                
                            <h3>DC Comics</h3>                              
                            <?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>    
                            <?php if($category['children'][$i]['class'] == "DC Comics"){ ?>
                            <li>
                                <ul>                                                                                                                                              
                                  <?php if (isset($category['children'][$i])) { ?>  
                                        <li><a href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['name']; ?></a></li>
                                  <?php } ?>                                                                        
                                </ul>
                            </li>   
                             <?php } ?>
                            <?php } ?>                                  
                            <h3>Marvel</h3>                             
                            <?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>    
                            <?php if($category['children'][$i]['class'] == "Marvel"){ ?>
                            <li>
                                <ul>                                                                                                                                              
                                  <?php if (isset($category['children'][$i])) { ?>  
                                        <li><a href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['name']; ?></a></li>
                                  <?php } ?>                                                                        
                                </ul>
                            </li>   
                             <?php } ?>
                            <?php } ?>                              
                        </ul>
                        <?php } ?>   
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </li>   
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>           
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Look at your `for` loop condition again. `for (; $i < $j; $i++) {` -- how do you expect this to execute correctly? :)

Comment: Wow, what a nice spaghetti code. Makes me hungry looking at it.

Comment: Can you please add a sample of `$category` array?

Comment: Using of `foreach` is highly recommended as `foreach` is **quicker** than `for` loop. And it prevents calling of nested `for(; $i < $j; $i++)` five times in one template... One advice though: when implementing things in OpenCart, look how they are implemented and try to **follow that style** and **re-use present code** as much as possible...

Answer (score 2):

Use `different variables` in `loops`, in you `code` `$i` is used in `main loop` and `incremented` in `inner loops` you can use `foreach loop` like ,

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <li><a href="#"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
    <?php if (is_array($category['children']) and isset($category['children'])) { ?> 
        <div class="subs">
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <?php 
                        $li1='<li><h3>DC Comics</h3><ul>';
                        $li2='<li><h3>Marvel</h3><ul>';
                        foreach($category['children'] as $child)
                        {
                           if($child['class'] == "DC Comics")
                           {
                              $li1.='<li><a href="'.$child['href'].'">'.$child['name'].'</a></li>';
                           }
                           if($child['class'] == "Marvel")
                           {
                              $li2.='<li><a href="'.$child['href'].'">'.$child['name'].'</a></li>';
                           }
                        }
                        $li1.='</ul></li>';
                        $li2.='</ul></li>'; 
                        echo $li1;
                        echo $li2;                            
                    ?> 
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </li>   
<?php } ?>
```